# Passing Time Frame parameters in Report?

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, dynamic-visualforce

I need to pass report parameters from VF page.?

I want to run a report from Thursday to Friday dynamically...
I have the dates on Vf page...

But how to pass in the report URL.

```
https://na5.salesforce.com/00O70000004aO3f?startDate=29/09/2008&Enadate29/09/2015
```

Answer (score 1):

One option I can think of is sending parameter vis URL to the filter criteria-

Note that **pv0, pv1, pv2** are the individual filter criteria items for you report. So effectively kindly edit the report and for the first criteria line put in

"Created Date" greater than or equal to   --- and then leave the third column blank

For the second put in 
"Created Date" Less then or equal to -- and then leave the column blank

and so on.....

so your URL should be like https://na5.salesforce.com/00O70000004aO3f&pv0={Start_date}&pv1={end_date}

Comment: Its still not working https://na5.salesforce.com/00O70000004aO3f?pv0=09/29/2008&pv1=09/30/2015...Instead it is assigning to  1. Assigned contains 09/29/2008 
     2. Subject contains 09/30/2015 ..I want Time Frame

Comment: Did you maintain proper sequence...  It assigns sequentially

Comment: I used pv0 and pv1..is that not right.?

Comment: What are the criterias in your report...

Comment: I have 2 dates in apex class...One is start date and one is end date..I want to use these 2 dates to set the time frame start and end date in the report.

Comment: In the report as mentioned in the answer you will have to add criterias where you want to replace these dates. if you can add a screenshot of report filter that will help. Also when you say start and end date do you mean you want to fetch records CREATED between these dates?

Comment: Yes...Exactly..fetch records CREATED between the dates

Comment: there you go , editted answer, this should help !

Comment: What change you did it looks same :)

Comment: Basically add 'createddate' in 1st and 2nd report filter criteria